# Selecting column value based on another table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have two tables, one of which contains many fields including fldANA and fldPROD and another table which contains the same two fields. Not all fldANA and fldPROD fields have a matching value in table 2 however and so I don't know as if I can really join the fields? The following is what my query currently looks like but it's returning 10's or 1000's more records than it is supposed to.

```
SELECT  Line#, CastID, 
        (CASE WHEN #sRst1.PROD = FN_qryIDs.fldANA AND #sRst1.PROD =
                                                   FN_qryIDs.fldPROD
        THEN FN_qryIDs.fldANA ELSE #sRst1.ANA END) AS ANA, 
        (CASE WHEN #sRst1.PROD = FN_qryIDs.fldANA AND #sRst1.PROD = 
                                                   FN_qryIDs.fldPROD
        THEN FN_qryIDs.fldCONN ELSE #sRst1.CONN END) AS CONN 
INTO #sRst2
FROM #sRst1
WHERE CastID <> '' AND PROD <> '' AND ANA <> ''
```

Comment: Have you tried to `left join` both tables. `select * from fn_qryIDs t1 left join #sRst1  t2 on t1.fldANA=t2.ANA and t1.fldPROD=t2.PROD`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ehm, not sure about the source schema but hopefully this should at least get you on the right path.

```
SELECT R1.[Line#], R1.CastID
  ,ISNULL(Q.fldANA, R1.ANA) [ANA]
  ,ISNULL(Q.fldCONN, R1.CONN) [Conn]
FROM #sRst1 R1
LEFT JOIN FN_qryIDs Q ON Q.fldANA = R1.PROD
  AND Q.fldPROD = R1.PROD
WHERE R1.CastID <> ''
  AND R1.Prod <> ''
  AND R1.ANA <> ''
```